# mongodb / node - ignore certain object properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to tell `MongoClient` that there are some properties I don't want to store? For example, I have some properties that are cyclic dependencies which fail to serialize - this causes a few problems. I'd rather not have to set them to null before I save them every time, then re-instate those variables when the insert has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with a little help from the [`omit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/) method of the underscore (or lodash) library.  That will cleanly create a copy of your object without the problematic properties.

```
var objectToInsert = _.omit(fullObject, 'badField1', 'badField2');
collection.insert(objectToInsert, callback);
```

Another way to go is to use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) which lets you define schemas for your collections so that only those fields in the schema get included when saved.

Comment: Great suggestion. Here I was struggling to find a way to do it with mongo, where I should have looked towards my dependencies.